# using prepared statements with Npgsql driver. Issue using IN

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

```
    var param = puuids.Select(puuid => "'" + puuid + "'").ToList();
    const string query = "SELECT puuid,CAST(data AS text) as data FROM match WHERE puuid in (@puuid);";
    using var conn = _databaseFactory.GetDatabase();
    using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter { ParameterName = "puuid", Value = string.Join(',', param) });
    cmd.Prepare();
    using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If I concatenate param into the query it works fine, but it's not ideal. I was wondering how i could get this to work with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to =ANY, like `puuid =ANY(?)`.  It takes an array rather than a list, so then you can bind an entire array to one placeholder.

```cs
const string query = @"
SELECT
  puuid,
  CAST(data AS text) as data
FROM match
WHERE puuid = ANY(@puuid);
";
using var conn = _databaseFactory.GetDatabase();
using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("puuid", NpgsqlDbType.Text | NpgsqlDbType.Array, puuids.ToArray());
using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: This worked thank you! To bind the array i did: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("puuid", NpgsqlDbType.Text | NpgsqlDbType.Array, puuids.ToArray());`